# Solve optimization under constraint

Tags: analysis, optimization

Given a function that is to be maximized:

$f(x,y,z) = 1/2 * x - y$

subject to:

$g1(x,y,z) = x - e^{-x} - y + z^{2} ≤ 0$

$g2(x,y,z) = -x ≤ 0$

I started with the first order conditions:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} &= \frac{1}{2} - \lambda_1 - \lambda_1 * e^{-x} + \lambda_2 = 0 \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} &= -1 + \lambda_1 = 0 \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial z} &= 2z\lambda_1 = 0 \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_1} &= x - e^{-x} - y + z^2 = 0 \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda_2} &= -x = 0 \\
\end{align*}$$

But be aware that I changed $≤$ to $=$. This provides me with the following solution:
$x=0, y=-1, z=0, \lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = 1.5$.

How do we approach the case where the constraints are $<$ rather than equal like above?

Comment: Are you familiar with Kuhn-Tucker plus Lagrange Multipliers ?

Comment: Note that $f$ is linear so the minima/maxima should be located at the boundary when the equality is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both constraints were of the type "<", then the constrained set would be open, and you would have to find the maximum of a differentiable function in an open set. If a point of maximum existed, then the gradient at that point would be zero according to the necessary condition for optimality. However, the gradient of a linear function, different from zero, is never zero. Therefore, you would have to search for a maximum on the boundary of the open set. To do this, you would need to set one of the constraints to zero.

Here are some hints to help you in your search:

If $g_2 = 0$ and $g_1 < 0$, the function becomes a one-variable function.

If $g_1 = 0$ and $g_2 < 0$, consider substituting a variable in $f$.

PS: I did not check the part you already did with the Lagrange multipliers because it was not part of your question.